# replace characters with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Morning,

I need to replace some characters in jQuery with different characters due to the way images are displayed on the site. I need to replace the & and the / with an _

I currently have, how would i do the / ?

```
$('#lnkProdImage').attr("href", "http://img.website.com/500/" + res.sku.replace(/&/g, '_').replace(/[\s]/g, '_') + ".jpg");
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `[&/\s]` as regular expression, to replace all those characters in one go. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ to learn more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#lnkProdImage').attr("href", "http://img.website.com/500/" + res.sku.replace(/&/g, '_').replace(/[\s]/g, '_').replace(/\//g, '_') + ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Seriously?

```
$('#lnkProdImage').attr("href", "http://img.website.com/500/" + res.sku.replace(/[&\s\/]/g, '_') + ".jpg");
```

Why the 3 replaces? Could be done in a single one!

Comment: i double checked, and certain images need different characters replaced :( not my coding someone else's I would of just replaced all with an _ personally.